# AWS - VPC - Network : How to troubleshoot AWS on-premise connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint, transit-gateway

the issue below is an issue i resolved after couple days of research. I expose it so i can have you point of view of how i could have spotted it faster looking at logs etc.

We have an hybrid AWS architecture. And my goal was to connect to redshift from on-premise.
The redshift serverless is

- on a VPC lets name it **cloud** with 3 AZones in 3 subnets : **rds1**/**rds2**/**rds3**.
- has a vpce-endpoint on the subnet **rds3** ( why this one ? i don't exactly know )
- attached to a security group where port **5439** is open for corresponding sources.

The VPC **cloud** :

- has a TransitGateway attachement  to 2 subnets **tgw1**/**tgw2** .

Route tables are correctly set.

When i try and connect to redshift; it **times out**. But when i check for **VPC FLOW LOGS**

```
fields @timestamp,@message
| filter dstPort = 5439
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Here is what i find :

> 2023-12-18T15:53:12.000+01:00 2 834242179416 eni-xxxxxxxxxxxx
> xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx 49801 5439 6 1 52 1702911192 1702911193 ACCEPT
> OK

so the call to redshift is well routed and accepted but no response never returns.

it appears that according to AWS DOC :

> When you attach a VPC to a transit gateway, any resources in
> Availability Zones where there is no transit gateway attachment cannot
> reach the transit gateway. If there is a route to the transit gateway
> in a subnet route table, traffic is forwarded to the transit gateway
> only when the transit gateway has an attachment in a subnet in the
> same Availability Zone.

So i added **rds3** to the attachment transit gateway and now it works.

but i wonder how i could've seen that directly from logs to identify the problem directly instead of reviewing all security gorups/  NACLS / route tables/ endpoints etc ...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The explanation is not clear. I would suggest to rewrite the question and give brief eplanation.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the Reachability Anayzer in the AWS Network Manager is very helpful in finding the source of these kind of issues.
You can trace from VPN Gateways all the way to specific IP addresses.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html